# Clickhouse uniqExact Aggregate function not work correctly

Tags: clickhouse

I have table with this schema

```
event_time DateTime,
field1 String,
field2 String,
field3 String
```

I want to create new table(`table`) with `SummingMergeTree` engine to aggregate data for some online queries. For this I create table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE aggregated_table(
  event_day DateTime,
  field1 String,
  field2 String,
  record_num UInt64,
  uniq_field3_state AggregateFunction(uniqExact, String)
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (event_day, field1, field2);
```

After that I insert my data to new table:

```sql
INSERT INTO aggregated_table
SELECT
  toStartOfDay(event_time) as event_day,
  field1,
  field2,
  count(*) AS request_num,
  uniqExactState(field3) As uniq_field3_state
FROM table
GROUP BY event_day, field1, field2;
```

Now, when I query to find `uniqExact` of `field3`:

```
select uniqExact(uniq_field3_state) from aggregated_table;
```

my answer is:

```
┌─uniqExact(uniq_field3_state)─┐
│                       356948 │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

but when I query the source table my answer is:

```
┌─uniqExact(field3)─┐
│             15548 │
└───────────────────┘
```

Is there any problem with this workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must finalize STATEs calculations by -Merge Or -Finalize functions.

In your example you have to use `uniqExactMerge` not uniqExact.

```
select uniqExactMerge(uniq_field3_state) 
from aggregated_table;
```